# Derby Network Server configuration

Tags: java, derby

I need Start and keep up Derby Network Server. I use Derby first time in my project. I am developing now and using `Embedded` Derby drivers without any problem. 
But when program ready to distribution it should has Network/Client support. I begin investigate Network Server configuration because of this.

Following [this](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html) article; I don't understand somethings. Let me ask it;

1-) Should i need set `ClassPaths` every time when Host start the program everytime via Command Prompt in Windows?

2-) I already add releated `jar` files to my Project as library. Should i distribute Derby bin release folder itself (about 33.7 MB) with my Project? (This question belongs to first question i think)

Comment: Do you want to run Derby as a service, i.e. independent of your application, or do you want to use it as an embedded database?

Comment: User create own database when program is first launched with `EmbeddedDriver` in Main PC. If it is first running sure i ask to user is it `Server` or `Client` setup. If it is Server i create database with `EmbeddedDriver` in where `Jar` file located. I need connect to DB as a Network Server at this time. And other client should connect to this database in `LAN`.

Comment: So I assume users on the LAN can only connect to the database when the application is running, if so then yes to both question, but in order for your database to be available on the LAN, you'll need to start it with the derbynet required libraries.

Comment: Also i find this line in the article for Start Network Server Easier Way; `C:\Apache\db-derby-10.4.1.3-bin\lib> java -jar derbyrun.jar server start` if i add this `derbyrun.jar` to my project as library, it is automaticly distributed and store in `lib` folder of where jar file located after compile. And i can execute above command in command prompt in Windows with Java command prompt support. We don't need distribute derby whole folder with program at this point i think. What you think abot this?

Comment: Using derbyrun.jar indeed makes your CLASSPATH simpler, but it doesn't remove the need to distribute the other derby jars. derbyrun.jar is simply a "wrapper" jar, which has no class files of its own, but instead simply uses the manifest classpath technique to automatically include the other jars in the CLASSPATH whenever derbyrun.jar is included in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Of course i should add other jars to to project (`derbytools` and `derbynet`) But we avoid the distrubute whole derby folder i think. I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seperate distrubution to two style. One of Server Setup, second of Client setup. I added whole jar files releated with derby to the project. These are stored in `lib` folder.

**Differences;**

**Server Setup** has extra one folder named `"DB"`. I added `derby.jar - derbyclient.jar - derbynet.jar - derbyrun.jar` to this folder too. When Server launches the program, go to `DB` folder and execute `derbyrun.jar` for set the `CLASSPATHS` every time. And boot the server.

When Server launches the program first time, Main Setup Window appear and user setup own credentials (LAN Ip, DB Name, Admin User Name&Password), execute `derbyrun.jar` and create the Database with given database name in `DB` folder.

**Client Setup** only have own `lib` folder. Because it not need start or stop derby database.